# How to return object with scala slick after insert

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to use generic insert function that would return object when inserting data using Slick.
I've tried with following code

```scala
        // This works without any issues but limited to specific entity and table
    def insertEmployee(employee: Employee): IO[Employee] = DB.run(db, {
        def returnObj = (EmployeeTable.instance returning EmployeeTable.instance.map(_.id)).into((obj, id) => obj.copy(id = id))
        returnObj += employee
    })
    
    // This doesn't work and returns error on "copy". Error: Cannot resolve symbol copy
    def withReturningObj[E <: BaseEntity, T <: BaseTable[E]](query: TableQuery[T]) =
        (query returning query.map(_.id)).into((obj, id) => obj.copy(id = id))
```

Anyone who could suggest a possible solution?

Comment: also asked at https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/10il9tb/how_to_define_a_function_to_return_an_object_when/

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you haven't defined your own `copy` method and are trying to use the one synthesized for case classes. The problem here is that `obj` isn't known to be of a type that has a `copy` method, just that it is a `BaseEntity`. I've had this same issue though, as unfortunately there isn't actually a way to constrain a type parameter to be a case class (that I know of, I would LOVE to be wrong about this though). I ended up doing something equivalent to defining a `withId()` method in your `BaseEntity` for specifically this purpose.

```scala
trait BaseEntity {
    val id: IdType
    def withId(id: IdType): BaseEntity
}

// ...
def withReturningObj[E <: BaseEntity, T <: BaseTable[E]](query: TableQuery[T]) =
        (query returning query.map(_.id)).into((obj, id) => obj.withId(id) // <-- use withId here instead of copy
```